# apache2 Chef cookbook start failure

Tags: apache2, chef-infra, recipe, cookbook

I'm trying to use Chef to create a local virtual host and for that I had added the "recipe[apache2]" recipe in my runlist and it worked great until I also added another recipe in the runlist that includes the default apache2 recipe. Now, even if I remove the new recipe from the runlist action 'start' fails with the following error. Anyone knows what's the reason for this?

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[apache2]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /etc/init.d/apache2 start ----
STDOUT: * Starting web server apache2
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
STDERR: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf:
ServerName takes one argument, The hostname and port of the server
---- End output of /etc/init.d/apache2 start ----
Ran /etc/init.d/apache2 start returned 1


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache2/recipes/default.rb

210: service 'apache2' do
211:   action :start
212: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache2/recipes/default.rb:210:in `from_file'

service("apache2") do
  action [:start]
  supports {:restart=>true, :reload=>true, :status=>true}
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  service_name "apache2"
  pattern "apache2"
  restart_command "/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d apache2 restart && sleep 1"
  reload_command "/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d apache2 reload && sleep 1"
  cookbook_name "apache2"
  recipe_name "default"
end



[2014-03-04T17:52:20+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before         re-raising exception
[2014-03-04T17:52:20+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-03-04T17:52:20+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-03-04T17:52:20+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-03-04T17:52:20+00:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: 3d91fc5b-cf02-4788-bb56-f03ebe274702)
[2014-03-04T17:52:21+00:00] ERROR: service[apache2] (apache2::default line 210) had an  error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /etc/init.d/apache2 start ----
STDOUT: * Starting web server apache2
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
STDERR: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf:
ServerName takes one argument, The hostname and port of the server
---- End output of /etc/init.d/apache2 start ----
Ran /etc/init.d/apache2 start returned 1
[2014-03-04T17:52:21+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf`: The output says

> ServerName takes one argument, The hostname and port of the server

Obviously, you're not passing the `sever_name` attribute - have a look at the [README](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2#web_app) and at the used [template](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2/blob/master/templates/default/web_app.conf.erb#L2):

```rb
web_app "my_site" do
  server_name node['hostname']
  server_aliases [node['fqdn'], "my-site.example.com"]
  docroot "/srv/www/my_site"
end
```

If this doesn't help, please edit your post and add the code of how you define the *example* site.